# express js routes stop working and sending me could not get any reponse

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My express js old routes are working except for one and the new routes I am creating are not working getting **couldn't get any response** whenever I hit it on postman.

[Sample response image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQoLI.png)

This is my app.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var helpers = require("./helpers/")();
var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var purchase = require('./routes/purchase');
var driver = require('./routes/driver');
var notification = require('./routes/notification');
var admin = require('./routes/admin');
var test = require('./routes/test');

var app = express();

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/myapp");
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
//file upload


app.use(function (req, res, next) {

  var oldWrite = res.write;
  var oldEnd = res.end;
  var chunks = [];
  // models.Logger.req = req;
  res.write = function (chunk) {

    chunks.push(chunk);
    oldWrite.apply(res, arguments);
  };
  res.end = function (chunk) {
    if (chunk) chunks.push(chunk);
    if (helpers.general.count(chunk) < 2) {
      var buff100 = new Buffer(100);
      chunks.push(buff100);
    }
    if (typeof chunks == "object") {
      console.log(res.statusCode);
      if (
        res.statusCode != 401 &&
        res.statusCode != 404 &&
        res.statusCode != 302 &&
        res.statusCode != 500
      ) {
        var body = Buffer.concat(chunks).toString("utf8");
        console.log(body);
        var bstatus = JSON.parse(body);
        if(!bstatus.status){
          res.statusCode = 422;
        }
        // models.Logger.req = req;
        // models.Logger.logInternal(req, body);
      }
    }

    if (res.statusCode == 401) {
      var unauth = JSON.stringify({
        'status': 'false',
        'message': 'Invalid Reseller Credentials'
      });
      res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json;')
      res.setHeader('charset', 'utf-8')
      arguments[0] = unauth;
      // models.Logger.logInternal(req, unauth);
    }

    oldEnd.apply(res, arguments);
  };
  next();
});

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/purchase', purchase);
app.use('/driver', driver);
app.use('/notification', notification);
app.use('/admin', admin);
app.use('/test', test);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

And this is my simple route file which is also not working

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.json({ title: 'Express' });
  });
module.exports = router;
```

When I try getting this simple test route it send me couldn't get any response. Even my npm start don't break and even don't show me any error. I was using pm2 too and it also don't get any error to track. I have also tried node debugger on vscode by adding breakpoints still unable to to find any error which could help me in solving this problem.

This is my www file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('vero:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3001');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

Comment: So the obvious questions: Is your app running? What does your app.listen() look like? Is something else running on that port (like an old instance of the app that didnt close correctly)?) (If restarting the app gives EADDRINUSE, Address already in use that's a big hint)

Comment: I have tried changing port its also don't give me any error. Yes my app is running and my old all routes are giving me response.

Comment: I have also added my www file for reference

Comment: In your picture it says your trying to hit a route on locahost (misspelled - you are missing an L in local). Is that the issue?

Comment: @maxpaj thank you. Yes that was the issue. my bad I forgot to see the spelling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Make sure you app is running**. Debug your code and put a breakpoint in the `listening` event listener or simply check for the debug print in the console.

You can also run `netstat` in a terminal window and check for a socket that is listening on your apps port. Sample output could look something like this (see first line in the table):

```
maxpaj@maxpaj-VirtualBox:~/code/app$ netstat -ntlp
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2829/node
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:28594         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2829/node
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8443            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2829/node
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

**Make sure you are hitting the correct address and route**. Check the spelling of the address, port and route. Could be as simple as that. I see that in your sample picture it says your trying to hit a route on **locahost** (misspelled - you are missing an L in local). Could that be the issue?

Comment: yup missing l from localhost was the issue thank you :)